# Incorrect checksum for freed object malloc

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error:

```
Ladder(59595,0x1045a4580) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x143605550: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x30
Ladder(59595,0x1045a4580) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

for the program below. It still runs but spits the malloc after.

ladder.h:

```
#ifndef LADDER_H
#define LADDER_H
#include <string>
void create_ladder(std::string pattern[], int size);
#endif // LADDER_H
```

ladder.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void create_ladder(std::string pattern[], int size){

    for (int i=0; i <= size; i++){ //function to repeat a string of the int "size" "size" number of times
        std::string size_str, pat; // declare strings
        std::stringstream ss; //declare stringstream to convert "size" to a string
        ss << i+1; //convert int "i" + 1 to a string
        ss >> size_str; //sends the converted string to a new string "size_str"
        size_str = size_str + " "; //adds the space to the string

        for (int j=0; j <= i; j++){ //function to repeat the string "i" number of times and put that into a new string
                pat += size_str;
                pattern[i] = pat; // stores the string of strings in the element of the array "pattern"
            }


    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include "ladder.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int size = 5;
    std::string *pattern1 = new std::string[size]; // Dynamic array of strings
    create_ladder(pattern1, size); // Calling to create the ladder
    for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        std::cout << pattern1[i]<< std::endl;
    }
    delete[] pattern1; // Don't forget to reclaim memory
    // Print the patterns for size = 9 and 15 respectively. Do not print empty lines

    size = 9;
    std::string *pattern2 = new std::string[size]; // Dynamic array of strings
    create_ladder(pattern2, size); // Calling to create the ladder
    for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        std::cout << pattern2[i]<< std::endl;
    }
    delete[] pattern2; // Don't forget to reclaim memory

    size = 15;
    std::string *pattern3 = new std::string[size]; // Dynamic array of strings
    create_ladder(pattern3, size); // Calling to create the ladder
    for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        std::cout << pattern3[i]<< std::endl;
    }
    delete[] pattern3; // Don't forget to reclaim memory

    return 0;
}
```

it appears to have something to do with the third pattern where the int "size" has 2 digits. It only occurs when size is an int that has more than 1 digit. Can any of you fine folks help explain why?

Thank You,

Comment: In general look more closely at the code when you see a `<=` in the exit condition of a loop iterating a list. It's an off-by-one more often than not.

Comment: In addition, you can use templates and let the compiler determine the length of the arrays. `template <size_t len> string[] f(string[len]) {}`

Comment: use a std::array. An array of 15 strings is tiny and certainly fits on the stack. Try to only use the heap for big objects or when the ownership changes hands.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i=0; i <= size; i++){  
    //function to repeat a string of the int "size" "size" number of times
```

Suppose `size` is three. This loop *should* repeat three times. And the comment says it will repeat three times. But it repeats four times. Starting from zero, there are *four* numbers that are less than or equal to three -- zero, one, two, and three.

You want `i < size;`, not `i <= size;`.

Comment: of course! this fixed the malloc. thank you!